# Urldate field gets ignored

Tags: natbib, urls, harvard-style

I need help :)

I am writing in Danish and need citations in the harvard style. I am using the following minimum setup:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[Danish,english]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{har2nat}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\usepackage[colorlinks, linkcolor = black, citecolor = black, filecolor = black, urlcolor = blue]{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\harvardurl}[1]{\textbf{URL:} \url{#1}}
\usepackage{breakcites}
\renewcommand*{\UrlFont}{\itshape}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{danish}
\bibliography{mybib}
\nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

with for example following bibiographic entry:

```
@TechReport{AgnSchu2009,
author={Agnello, Luca and Schuknecht, Ludger},
title={{Booms and busts in housing markets: Determinants and implications}},
year=2009,
month=Jul,
institution={European Central Bank},
type={Working Paper Series},
url={http://ideas.repec.org/p/ecb/ecbwps/20091071.html},
urldate={01.04.2014},
number={No. 1071},
}
```

In principle it works well, and I am happy with the style and the hyperlinks etc BUT the urldate field gets ignored. I would need a solution that works also for @article, @misc, @booklet, @incollection entries. Tried using the "note" field but then the date of last access ends in front of the URL (and not after it, where it belongs).

If you then also could help me with two more 'esthetic' problems: the URLs are set on a new line (I would like them to just continue on the last line of the literature entry) and (of course) URL linebreaks look funny (but I guess that i will have to change manually...)

Help is very much appreciated. I am no LaTeX expert - so please be patient :)

Comment: I did not try but I'm pretty sure urldate should be formatted like this: `YYYY-MM-DD'. So in you're bibliographic entry: `urldate={2014-04-01}`.

Comment: I do not think the `urldate` key is even supported by the `agsm` bibtex style. Probably better to write it in a `note={...}` instead. (I searched the `agsm.bst` file). Also unless your style actually supports languages, then it does not make any sense to specify `danish` just before the bibliography. It seems to be using `\harvardand` so you might be in luck here.

Answer (score 1):

If changing to Biblatex is acceptable, then it has support for `urldate`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,danish]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\usepackage[colorlinks, linkcolor = black, citecolor = black,
            filecolor = black, urlcolor = blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Foo \parencite{AgnSchu2009}.
% \nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and in the bib file change to

```
urldate={2014-04-01},
```

Now running first LaTeX, then `biber`, then LaTeX again, you will get
[image]

Notes:

- There are variants and lots of options for the `authoryear` style. I don't know which one(s) is most like the style you were using.
- I removed your special formatting of urls, thinking you should see the default now before maybe doing something about it again.
- The *last* language to `babel` is set to current language at the beginning of the document.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I had tried something similar in the beginning but not used biber... Changed the settings in the editor and now it worked. I just put back the url into italics. Thank you again for your quick help!

Comment: I would like to point out that the correct formatting of the date is really necessary for the `urldate` to show up. It took me four hours to figure that out :-)

Comment: Then you should have received a warning from biber about "Invalid format ... of date field urldate"!